# How to implement Hierarchical queries in JPA?

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, microservices

I have a huge oracle database with large number of stored procedures which I need to convert in microservice. In one of those procedures there is a hierarchical query in the form of :-

```
Select column_names from table_name start with column_name in (subquery) connect by nocycle prior (condition)
```

I need to convert this functionality into java code as I don't know how to use this in JPA query and I also cannot use native query. As I understand, this sort of query returns data in a tree like structure. I need to maintain that same structure as I further want to join this to another view. I would like to know how can I implement such a functionality in java using simple JPA queries ?

Comment: You can't. JPQL does not support hierarchical queries. You'll need to use a native query

Comment: I can't , we need to keep our codebase independent of database, even if we are using oracle now we might not be using it in the future. So I just wanted to know how to implement this functionality within java itself

Comment: This seems related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73571558/how-to-do-hierarchical-queries-in-jpa