# How to do Hierarchical queries in JPA?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two Tables like following :

[image]

What would be the query to show data in the format by using JPA & Hibernate? Should I use group by?

My Products :

1. P1

   - User u2@email.com

     1. P2

     - User u3@email.com

       1. P3

Comment: For a complex reporting requirement like this, you may want to use a native query with a recursive hierarchical CTE (if your database support it).  You could also create a stored procedure.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you. Is there any better approach to design the database for this? I have used MySql database.

Comment: Your table design is pretty standard.

Comment: To write CTE with JPA you may use FluentJPA - https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA/wiki/Common-Table-Expressions

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your associations or what result you want, but you can use [Blaze-Persistence](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.6/core/manual/en_US/#recursive-ctes) on top of JPA to do recursive CTEs until I add support for the WITH clause to Hibernate :)